# Magento 2 REST API placing order with Braintree Credit Card error

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api, braintree

Magento version: 2.2.0

I'm trying to place order with Braintree credit card.
The payload I send is:

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
    "method": "braintree",
    "additional_data": {
      "cc_cid": "000",
      "cc_type": "VI",
      "cc_exp_year": "2019",
      "cc_exp_month": "2",
      "cc_number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

But I've got error "Transaction has been declined. Please try again later."

The data I use is valid, because I can successfully place order with these data via frontend.
Also, I'm sure that my API calls are valid, because I can place order via API using other payment method like "Check / Money order"

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

If the transaction was declined, the bank has refused to accept the transaction. You will need to login to your Braintree account to see the [decline reason code](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/declines#authorization-decline-codes). Ultimately, your or the customer's bank would have more information about why a specific transaction is being declined by the bank.